# Representing views across several RelativeLayouts in one list item

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to have 3 text views in one list item. The challenge is that this list item is formatted like a card, with two different colors (pictured here). I accomplished the different colors through creative 2 different `RelativeLayout` [image: Pictured here].

My XML is formatting this list items correctly, however it's not containing all 3 views. It ends up creating 3 list items 2 that contain only `{view 2}` and one that only contains `{view 1}`. What is causing the below XML to not group all 3 views into one list item and how can it be remedied?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/outer"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="#08445e"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRoom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Room "
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time: "
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/inner"
        android:background="#d1d1d1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/outer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you want to align text or wanted card view shadow?

Comment: Why don't you use linear layout instead of relative layout ??

Answer (score 0):

try this I have made some changes in your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/outer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#08445e">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRoom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Room {room}"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Time: {Time} sec"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/outer"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:background="#d1d1d1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="{View 1}"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // must check the result to prevent exception
do {
   String msgData = "";
   for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
   {
       msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
   }
   // use msgData
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

May this code helps you